# Same table inner-join a table on 2 conditions and either conditions are sometimes false

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Details:

1. `V` and `C` are tables
2. I want `C` to join `V` on 2 conditions(two C are named `C0` and `C1`). Since I must filter `V` by columns of `C` and `C`'s child tables separately in the same query, I think joining is needed.
3. `V` has many, at least one `C`, and either `Cx` sometimes doesn't exist.

Because of 3., using inner join to `C0` and `C1` sometimes cause empty result, but I don't want get `V`'s white area.

Schema:

```
V (id)
C (id, v_id, name, type)
```

Query(1):

```
SELECT V.* 
FROM V
INNER JOIN C AS C0 ON V.id = C0.v_id WHERE C0.type = 0
INNER JOIN C AS C1 ON V.id = C1.v_id WHERE C1.type = 1
WHERE C0.name = 'word' or C1.name = 'word'
WHERE C0.name like '%wo%'
```

Query (2):

```
SELECT V.* 
FROM V
INNER JOIN C AS C0 ON V.id = C0.v_id WHERE C0.type = 0
INNER JOIN C AS C1 ON V.id = C1.v_id WHERE C1.type = 1
WHERE C0.name = 'word' or C1.name = 'word'
WHERE C1.name like '%wo%'
```

`WHERE C0.name = 'word' or C1.name = 'word'`: This clause exists every time.

`WHERE Cx.name like '%wo%'`: This clause depends on the time.

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask SQL questions on Stack Overflow. Would you please have a look at [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query), and try to improve the quality of your question so it meets SO standards?

Comment: things will be more clear if you post the V and C table schema

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor explanation. I didn't understand what I want to do.
Thanks to your answers, I was able to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... You seem to be looking for an `EXISTS` condition with correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM v 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM c WHERE c.c0 = v.c0 OR c.c1 = v.c1)
```

This will return all records in table `v` for which at least one record exists in table `c` that satisfies either condition `c.c0 = v.c0` or condition  `c.c1 = v.c1`.

In this situation, the advantage of the correlated subquery against the `JOIN` approach is that it avoids multiplying records when more than one match exists in table `c`.

If you want to exclude records that meet either condition instead of including them, then just change `WHERE EXISTS` to `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Good point on EXIST to prevent duplicates, but their question ambiguity very bad for getting help.

Comment: ! agree SOME to the link reference to MCVE.  Most people do provide descent information and don't need the bloated overload on every question.  Sometimes people throw that as a comment so often its somewhat scary, especially beginners who can't even describe what they don't understand.  I've answered many that never had the level of detail MVCE asks for, but it also takes READING the question and you were able to offer workable solution without it too  :)

Comment: @DRapp: yes I agree with you that the answerer also needs to make a real effort to understand the question, even when it does not meet the somehow rigid requirements on the SQL tag. I also answered many of such questions, often succesfully. I guess it's always a matter of assessing how sure you are that you correctly understand what is being asked VS asking for clarification from OP.

Answer (score 2):

bad ask / details of the question, knowing a better context of what you want, even if abbreviated fields and actual tables could help better in the future.  However, it looks like what you want is an "IN" condition based on EITHER of the "C" aliased conditions.  Without seeing them, you can look at it like this (or simplified both criteria in second).

```
select
      v.*
   from
      VTable v
         LEFT JOIN CTable C0
            on v.SomeField = C0.SomeField
         LEFT JOIN CTable C1
            on v.SomeOtherField = C1.SomeOtherField
   where
          c0.SomeField IS NOT NULL
      OR c1.SomeField IS NOT NULL
```

OR... simplified with a single left-join, combining both criteria

```
select
      v.*
   from
      VTable v
         LEFT JOIN CTable C0
            on ( ( v.SomeField = C0.SomeField )
              OR ( v.SomeOtherField = C0.SomeOtherField ) )
   where
      c0.SomeField IS NOT NULL
```

I used extra parenthesis in the above query in case the original C0 and C1 conditions were complex in themselves.

So what you described as the white area in the "V" table is in simple English is give me everything from the V table that does NOT match EITHER of the C0 or C1 conditions.  Hence the left-join and then ENSURING they DO exist by checking for any column (expect a key column though) to explicitly BE NOT NULL (hence it does exist in the C table criteria).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want columns from `v`, then `exists` comes to mind.

I would phrase this as:

```
select v.*
from v
where exists (select 1
              from c
              where v.id = c.v_id and
                    c.type = 0
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from c
              where v.id = c.v_id and
                    c.type = 1
             ) ;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `c(v_id, type)`.

It should also be fine to phrase this as:

```
select v.*
from v
where exists (select 1
              from c
              where v.id = c.v_id and
                    c.type in (0, 1)
             );
```

Or even:

```
select v.*
from v
where v.id in (select c.v_id
               from c
               where c.type in (0, 1)
              );
```

The key idea is that by doing the comparison in the `where` clause, you are guaranteeing that rows cannot be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join table c two times, you can write your query like following.

```
select V.*
from V as V
inner join C as C on C.v_id=V.id 
where C.name='word' and C.type in(0,1)
```